# Use string variable instead of string it Excel VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel, variables

I'm fully new with Excel VBA and struggling already for hours to use a string variable instead of writing the string. Probably a very simple solution, however I cannot seem to find similar cases nor did anything I tried work out :s

I define a variable name NewSbWb (= "REQ1351") as following

```
Dim NewSbWb As String
NewSbWb = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D2").Value
```

if I then use functions such as the following:

```
Workbooks("REQ1351").Activate
```

or

```
currentSheet.Copy Before:=Workbooks("REQ1351").Sheets(sheetIndex)
```

I would like to use the string variable NewSbWb instead of writing "REQ1351".

I hope one of you can help me. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply: `Workbooks(NewSbWb).Activate`

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim NewSbWb As String
NewSbWb = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D2").Value
Workbooks(NewSbWb).Activate
currentSheet.Copy Before:=Workbooks(NewSbWb).Sheets(sheetIndex)
```